# Update an array inside a model in Backbone

Tags: arrays, backbone.js

I have an array inside my model that is:

```
accountRuleMessages: Array[1]
     0: Object
        ruleKey: "abc"
        ruleMessage: "error"
```

I want to update update this array within my application based on a condition, thats like:

```
this.model.set('accountRuleMessages', { "ruleKey": "123","ruleMessage": "new message" });
```

But this now sets the array like this:

```
accountRuleMessages: Object
       ruleKey: "123"
       ruleMessage: "aa"
```

Is this the right way to go about it? Please confirm!

Comment: this.model.set('accountRuleMessages', [0][{ "ruleKey": "123","ruleMessage": "new message" }]);

Comment: I'm not 100% that will work

Answer (score 0):

You are better off having a nested collection inside the model instead of a plain Array.

If `accountRuleMessages` comes from a server as an Array, in the model's `parse` method you can convert it to a `Backbone.Collection`.

Then updating it is easy using collection methods:

```
var firstMessage = this.model.get('accountRuleMessages').at(0);
firstMessage.set({
  ruleKey: "123",
  ruleMessage: "new message"
});
```

If you want to use a vanilla Array though:

```
var accountRuleMessages = this.model.get('accountRuleMessages');
accountRuleMessages[0] = {
  ruleKey: "123",
  ruleMessage: "new message"
}
```

Should work since the Array is passed around by reference so you can directly modify it. However you won't be able to do useful stuff like "when the messages change, re-render this messages list" like you would with a collection.

Pro tip: if you do make it a collection, it will be a good idea to use Model's which have the [idAttribute](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-idAttribute) set to `ruleKey` so you can use `collection.get` and other goodies.